# deleting multiple rows based on a variety of numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Sorry for the silly question, but I have a huge dataframe (called "`totaldecade`") with columns named:

```
Event.ID,Event.Date,CAMEO.Code
```

I want to delete all rows that have number ranges: `10:58, 90:145, 1011:1454, 160:166, 1661:1663,` within the `CAMEO:Code` column.

I have tried:

```
totaldecade[with(totaldecade, !((CAMEO.Code %between% 10:58) | 
(CAMEO.Code %between% 90:145) | 
(CAMEO.Code %between% 1011:1454) | (CAMEO.Code %between% 160:166) | 
(CAMEO.Code %between% 1661:1663))), ]
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Michelle

Answer (score 0):

We get the ranges in a vector, use `%in%` to create the logical vector and negate (`!`) to change the FALSE elements to TRUE and viceversa

```
library(dplyr)
totaldecade %>% 
       filter(!CAMEO.Code %in% c(10:58, 90:145, 1011:1454, 160:166, 1661:1663))
```

---

Or using `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(totaldecade, !CAMEO.Code %in% c(10:58, 90:145, 1011:1454, 
                    160:166, 1661:1663))
```